# How to clone a laravel project form bitbucket and install and run in your computer with Sourcetree?

Tags: php, laravel, xampp, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

I want full step to step work to clone a laravel project in my computer and also to run it properly !

Comment: What's the point in asking a question and answereing it in the same second?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Check your php,composer version & git**

- Click `Ctrl` + `r` and type *cmd*
- Type `php -v` to check your php version in your command line.
- [If your php version is more than 5.6 you are good to go ! ]
- [If your php is not installed or even php version is less than 5.6, then store your htdocs from
  Xampp and uninstall Xampp. Then install Xampp. Link is given below
  https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html]
- Type `composer -v` to check your composer version in your command line
- Type`composer update`
- [If composer is not installed,then download and install it. Link is given bellow https://getcomposer.org/download/]
- Type `git`
- [If git is not installed,then download and install it. Link is given bellow https://git-scm.com/downloads ]

**Sourcetree Authentication with bitbucket Repository**

- Download Sourcetree and install it. Link is given bellow https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/
- Login with Bitbucket mail & password. Then setup an SSH key with Sourcetree. Just follow the link given bellow https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/set-up-an-ssh-key-728138079.html#SetupanSSHkey-ssh3

**Run your Laravel project cloning from Bitbucket Repository**

- Now,just clone your project in your preferred location.
- Open your project in PhpStorm (or any other IDE you prefer).
- copy .evn.example file in a new .evn file in that folder. Edit DB_DATABASE, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD
- Create a folder naming `framework` in `storage` folder. then create 3 folders naming `sessions`,`views`,`cache` in `framework` folder.
- open IDE terminal.
- Type `composer update`
- Type `php artisan key:generate`
- Type `php artisan config:clear`
- Type `php artisan route:clear`
- Type `php artisan view:clear`
- Type `php artisan migrate`
- Type `php artisan serve`
- Open browser type `localhost:8000`

Ta Da !!! Your project is running fine in your browser.

Answer (score 5):

After cloning from bitbucket repository just run the following commands from your command line

1.composer install

2.copy .env.example .env (from your windows command promt)

3.php artisan key:generate

4.Now configure your database username,password,host etc
 in your .env file

5.php artisan serve

open your localhost
http://localhost:8000

you may need to run "php artisan config:clear" to 
clear cache

Thanks